# Is string initialization necessary in python?

Tags: python, string

Given this code:

```
  def double_char(str):
  result = ""
  for i in range(len(str)):
    result += str[i] + str[i]
  return result
```

Is `result = ""` the initialization of a string? If so, was it necessary to do in the first place?

Comment: Note that this whole thing is rather inefficient; it's better to join a list than to build a string a character at a time since with immutable strings this means creating a new string object every iteration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do

```
result += ...
```

it basically means that

```
result = result + ...
```

Python will not know the value `result` at this point. So, it will throw this error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment
```

Anyway, it is always better to initialize the variables.

**Suggestions**

1. Don't use `str` as a variable name, it hides the builtin [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function.
2. What you are trying to do, can be done in a single line, like this

   ```
   return "".join(i*2 for i in input_string)
   ```

---

```
def double_char(input_string):
  return "".join(i*2 for i in input_string)

print double_char("thefourtheye")           # tthheeffoouurrtthheeyyee
```

Answer (score 0):

While Python doesn't require you to state the type of a variable before using it (e.g. `int a = 10` instead of just `a = 10`), it is necessary for the variable `result` to exist before `+=` can be used with it.  Otherwise when you use `result += ...` Python will try `result = result + ...`.

As another suggestion, avoid naming a variable `str` since it overwrites the built-in `str` function/type in Python.